# Can I save webrtc offer for future connection?

Tags: webrtc

The purpose of this is to re-establish connection after refresh (or browser restart) without help of websocket server.

Note that connection has already been made. By sending offer thought QR code. PC-mobile connection.

PS. I'm actually trying to mimic WhatsApp Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. In particular ICE candidates will change on every connection.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Also thought, if device changes location, then the offer wouldn't be valid.

Comment: its not even ips. The ports are from the dynamic range and get closed when the connection is closed.

Comment: thanks. any ideas how to achieve whatsapp web like?